# What is the final 8 letter word?

Tags: word

Shown below are 3 boxes A, B and C

[image]

Box A shows 4 rows. Each row has a 3 letter blank. The 3  letters form a single word (same word for all 4 rows). After filling the blanks you should get 4 separate words.

Box B  shows 3 rows. Each row has a 2 letter blank. The 2 letters form a single word (same word for all 3 rows). After filling the blanks you should get 3 separate words.

Box C shows 4 rows. Each row has a 3 letter blank. The 3 letters form a single word (same word for all 4 rows). After filling the blanks you should get 4 separate words.

Now you have 3 separate words (one from each box) which will go in the 8 letter blank below to get your final answer, which is an eight letter word.

Comment: Did you make this puzzle yourself or find it elsewhere?

Comment: Made it myself. Spent a lot of time too!

Comment: +1 for the effort, and because this type of puzzle has merit. I'll suggest using less obscure words and avoiding abbreviations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DanielMathias. I tried less obscure words but my friends would solve the darn puzzle in no time. And knowing how good the puzzle solvers on this site are, I decided to go for the less obscure ones.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Credit to Stiv, for figuring out a different answer to **B** which makes a lot more sense. Also, worth giving an upvote to Rand al'Thor who had the same initial answer as me around the same time.

A

> I think this is [ANS](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ans) giving the words [**ANS**A](https://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/ansa), DE**ANS**, M**ANS**ES and F**ANS**

B

> This is WE, giving the words SO**WE**R, **WE**NT, **WE**D

C

> This is RED, giving the words C**RED**AL, **RED**E, SH**RED** and B**RED**

Putting them together gives

> **ANSWERED** (where, we've used A+B+C).

Previous answer

> REDBEANS (same as Rand al'Thor) with the answer for B being BE.

Comment: I couldn't get anything for the first one, but I think you probably want rot13(JR) for the middle one and then you need do no reordering at all!

Comment: @Stiv ah, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: Great job as always!

Answer (score 8):

Box A:

> I'm not sure about this one, couldn't find anything that fits properly. Given M???ES, I guess it must start with a vowel, and given DE???, I guess the vowel must be A. The best option I could think of was probably **ANS** (but ANS and ANSA aren't common words).

Box B:

> Pretty sure this is **BE**, for SOBER and BENT and BED.

Box C:

> Pretty sure this is **RED**, for CREDAL and REDE and SHRED and BRED.

The final word:

> Not sure if there's any word beginning with A and ending with BERED, but if we change the order we can get RED BEANS.