# What country are you in?

Tags: word

Shown below are 2 boxes A and B, each with 4 rows which represent 8 separate words. Rows in each box have 3 letter blanks which represent a single word. After solving the 2 boxes you will get 2 separate words which will go in the 6 letter box at the bottom which will help you answer the question:

**What country are you in?**

[image]

<sup>*Linked to [What is the final 8 letter word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120304/what-is-the-final-8-letter-word)*</sup>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Box A:

> **MAD**: **MAD**E, RE**MAD**E, **MAD**LY and PO**MAD**E.

Box B:

> **RID**:  **RID**E, A**RID**, P**RID**E, and **RID**ER.

Put together gives

> **MAD+RID**

So the country is

> **SPAIN**.