# I am a professional person

Tags: word

There are 3 boxes: A,B and C, each with 3 rows. Each row is a word. The blanks in each box are the same single word. After filling the blanks you will get 3 separate words (one from each box). Put them in the 7 letter box below to get the final answer. The words may not be in order.

[image]

Linked:[What country are you in?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120327/what-country-are-you-in)
[What is the final 8 letter word?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120304/what-is-the-final-8-letter-word?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe

> copilot

> **LOT**ion, s**LOT**ted, **LOT**s
> th**I**nk, sp**I**t, **I**n
> **COP**s, s**COP**e, **COP**es